# Drawing Box using Directx11 but do not show

Tags: graphics, pipeline, directx-11

I am writing a code of drawing a colorful box with Directx11 and the graphics do not show. Here's a screenshot of debugging graphics using visualstudio graphics debugger.
[image: debugsceenshot]

It seems like the vertex buffer or indices buffer is wrong, but I cannot find the problem.

I commit my code to github. Here is the url:
https://github.com/christliu/GraphicsAPI/tree/Effect/DirectX11.

Please tell me where is the problem.

Comment: Generally speaking, questions that are basically "Please debug my program" don't work well here on StackOverflow. You need to narrow it down as much as you can and create a clear, concise, and reproducible bit of code that you would like help with. For graphics debugging, you really need to validate each step individually because there could be a problem anywhere in your code. BTW, you may want to look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: Thank you for comment. I have found a problem using graphics debugger yesterday and I found that the API IASetIndexBuffer's second parameter I used was wrong and I have fixed it. The pipeline stage was right(the data of input output of shader stage).  But still I cannot see the picture. Since I have little experience of graphics programming I have no way to debug my code. I was totally confusing.

Comment: Finally I found the problem!. I changed the debug mode and I saw an error msg: D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets: The RenderTargetView at slot 0 is not compatible with the DepthStencilView. Then I googled it and changed the mEnable4xMsaa variable from True to False. Then the colorful box appeared!